# Cannot connect Ubuntu to network

Tags: networking, router, ubuntu-14.04

I recently moved and am having a few issues setting up my network.

I have a Raspberry Pi, a Win8.1 laptop, and an Ubuntu desktop. My RPi and laptop connect to the router/modem combo via Ethernet and WiFi, respectively, and both correctly receive IPs from DHCP. When I plug my Ubuntu in, though, it is not correctly connected to the network as far as I can tell.

One complication is that I do not have a monitor to view the Ubuntu's screen but I can edit files on the hard drive via an external drive if needed. I'm looking for the computer via a port scanner I found online as well as attempting to ssh, which worked just fine at my previous place of residence.

Two (possibly) interesting infos about the router/modem: the IP subnet is 192.168.0.* and when the Ubuntu is plugged into the Ethernet of the router a status page of the router (accessed from my laptop) shows that the link is correctly set up (compared to saying the link is down when unplugged). When I try to change the IP address of the router it says there is an address overlap and that it can't do it, which is weird.

I tried editing /etc/network/interfaces to give it a static IP to no avail, and also double checked the port in sshd_config

Any ideas would be very welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not trying to be mean but it sounds like you forgot to add the network which means you need to do that before you can ssh connect it via Ethernet and see your routers configuration to see what ip it gave to the Ubuntu machine. Then ssh in. Type this:

```
ifconfig
```

Then look for what looks like a wireless card.

Here you are going to look for available networks:

```
iwlist wlan0 s #change wlan0 for whatever your wifi card is
```

Then use this to add the network if it is oppen:

```
iwconfig wlan0 essid NAME_OF_ACCESS_POINT  #change NAME_OF_ACCESS_POINT to whatever network name you want
```

If the network has a password use the following command:

```
iwconfig wlan0 essid CYREX key PASSWORD #change CYREX to whatever network name you want and PASSWORD to you WEP or WPA key
```

you are connected.

Comment: I do not have a wireless dongle for the Ubuntu machine, it always has been connected with Ethernet. In addition, since I don't have a monitor for the machine nor a network connection, I basically have to rely on the system's automatic connection to the network based on settings I can change when I take the harddrive out of the Ubuntu and connect it to another computer. I suppose I can run programs via a startup script, so I'll try and run ifconfig that way and see what it comes up with.